# Base class declares virtual function whose parameter type depends on implementing class

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, design-patterns

My starting situation where I don't know what type to use in Base class:

```
class Base {
      private:
         virtual void doSomethingSpecific(?type param) = 0;
      public:
         // this function uses doSomethingSpecific
         void doSomething() {...}
    };
    
    class Derived1 : public Base {
      private:
         void doSomethingSpecific(Derived1Type param) override;
    };
    
    class Derived2 : public Base {
      private:
         void doSomethingSpecific(Derived2Type param) override;
    };
```

My solution using templates:

```
template<typename DerivedType>
class Base {
  private:
     virtual void doSomethingSpecific(DerivedType param) = 0;
  public:
     // this function uses doSomethingSpecific
     void doSomething() {...}
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1Type> {
  private:
     void doSomethingSpecific(Derived1Type param) override;
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2Type> {
  private:
     void doSomethingSpecific(Derived2Type param) override;
};
```

This works, but I am posting this because it feels like this my not be the most optimal/straightforward approach? Also even though the header files are simple, templates significantly increased compile time.

Here is a more specific example of how I use doSomethingSpecific function:

```
template<typename DerivedType>
class Base {
  std::vector<DerivedType> components;
  private:
     virtual void doSomethingSpecific(DerivedType param) = 0;
  public:
     Base(std::vector<DerivedType> components) {
        this->components = components;
     }
     // this function uses doSomethingSpecific
     void doSomething() {
        doSomethingSpecific(components[0]);     
     }
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1Type> {
  private:
     void doSomethingSpecific(Derived1Type param) override;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Derived1Type> components = {...};
    Derived1 obj(components);
    obj.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: looks like polymorphism without polymorphism. What is the intended use case? Suppose you write a `void foo(Base& b) { ..... }`, how do you plan to call the function?

Comment: or maybe no runtime polymorphism is needed. You will understand better your second approach if you read about CRTP

Comment: Don't use virtual functions for this. If you want to be able to reuse code from doSomethingSpecific you could use a template member function instead of making the whole class a template.

Comment: I mean either you want the funciton to be virtual or you want what you second code does, then there is no need for virtual. I think it would really help if you show example use case

Comment: Since you cannot call `pBase->doSomethingSpecific(?)`, this function should not be a part of `Base` interface.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) It is not obvious how the second approach is a solution to what the first code tries to get done (or what the first code tries to get done ;)
. Better tell us about the initial problem not only about your solutions

Comment: The name of the function should give you an hint. "SomethingSpecific" should be up to the derived classes. The base class is meant for "generic" things, applicable to all.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I am writing a small debugging library to use on GPIO Pins on different platforms. There is a base class with some debug logic and a deriving class (say a class for debugging on Raspberry PI GPIO pins). Base class needs to call a function that toggles a GPIO Pin, this function should take a parameter with an enum type specifing possible GPIO Pins (this is why this type depends on the deriving class). I guess that for my use case, using the Base type explicitly (like in your foo example) is not really needed, the base class is there as an interface and for some logic.

Comment: @PepijnKramer maybe my example was not clear enough, I am not passing the derived class type as template argument (Derived1 != Derived1Type), Derived1Type is a Derived1 specific type that needs to be passed to the base class to declare the virtual function correctly. I guess I could really avoid deriving classes by substituting them with function type template parameters (just pass doSomethingSpecific using templates) but in my real use case, I have multiple such doSomethingSpecific functions and it might make the template a bit heavy?

Comment: I do not understand all, but frankly this sounds like use of inheritance because it is considered the only / the best / the most obvious way of designing something. Thats a symptom of poor teaching, I have been there, and it took me long time to get over it. Fact is: inheritance is not the solution to everything. Can you explain what you want to do, what the aim of this is without using the words "inheritance" or "derived" ?

Comment: @n. m. Function is part of interface because it is called in doSomething function. I wanted to seperate Base class logic with specific derived class logic so when developing future derived classes it won't be necessary to take care of the Base class logic.

Comment: btw the question still stands: How do you intent to call `doSomethingSpecific` from within `doSomething` ? The different implementations do not have a common interface. It seems you try to squeeze them into one, but if they take different parameters then you need to pass different parameters. How do you want to do that?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so I created some logic for debugging on GPIO pins that is platform agnostic. I would like that future developers who plan to use this feature only need to add platform specific logic (such as GPIO initialization, GPIO toggling function etc.) without necessarily understanding how the underlying platform agnostic logic works. Is inheritance not the right tool in this case? I feel like without inheritance duplication of Base class logic would be needed (of course inheritance using classes could be substituted with templates).

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number good question, so I will be keeping a container of gpio pins of enum type. Then I will be just accessing them by index and using them in the virtual function (my logic will only depend on the specified order of pins).

Comment: sorry, I cannot follow. What I am asking for is an example implementation of `void doSomething() {...}` one that does not use `...` but actually calls `doSoemthingSpecific`. That call seems to be the whole reason for overriding and making the method virtual. In other words that would set the aim that you want to get somehow. Currently you are asking for a "better approach" but it is not quite clear what you want to approach. Btw I have posted a answer, if it answers your question then this discussion is not needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I updated a post with a more specific example.

Comment: ok, the confusing thing was just the first version of the code. There is no way to replace `...` with the actual implementation without changing `Base` in the first version of your code. And I was confused why you put that first as motivating example. Nevermind....

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah the first example was my original idea to just use a more general type for the function (for instance integer as you can static cast enum to integer if it's the underlying type). Thank you for telling me about CRTP, I now understand not to use inheritance when not actually using the base class.

Comment: It *cannot* be called from any function that is a part of `Base`.

Comment: I mean, it cannot be called in the first example. It can be called in the second example, but it's totally dofferent code. There is no common base anymore, there is a specific distinct base for each derived class, so there is no polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand the first example of your code. It is not clear why there is public inheritance and a virtual method. In the second example it is apparent there there is no need for the virtual method. `Base<A>` and `Base<B>` are two unrelated types. Consequently `Derived1` and `Derived2` do not share a common base. There is no runtime polymorphism.

For compile time polymorphism you can employ the CRTP (curiously recurring template pattern). Your code looks already very similar. The major change I had to make is to remove the overriding (its not needed):

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename T>
struct Base {
     void doSomething() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->doSomethingSpecific(typename T::type{});
     }
};

struct Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {
    using type = int;
     void doSomethingSpecific(type param) { std::cout << "hello int " << param; }
};

struct Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {
    using type = double;
    void doSomethingSpecific(type param) { std::cout << "hello double " << param; }
};

int main() {
    Derived1{}.doSomething();
    Derived2{}.doSomething();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9GTeT6WYG)

I also added a member alias `type` that `Base` can use to construct the parameter to pass to the methods. And for CRTP to work the base must be parametrized on the deriving class.

Again: `Derived1` and `Derived2` do not share a common base (as was the case already in your code).

Comment: I see that your code here is equivalent to mine, are there actually any differences regarding compiling or run time? Or is this just a more standard way of accomplishing what I intended?

Comment: @domenhočevar sorry, but you did not understand. This code is not equivalent to yours. There is no virtual function here. Yours is using runtime polymorphism, but its not actually gaining anything from that (at least in the parts you show). In the code in this answer there is no virtual method, no runtime polymorphism. You can read more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern